# Webpack cant resolve TypeScript modules

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, ts-loader

I build a relay small webpack and typescript demo to play with.
If i run webpack with the webpack.config.js i get this error:

```
ERROR in ./js/app.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './MyModule' in '/Users/timo/Documents/Dev/Web/02_Tests/webpack_test/js'
 @ ./js/app.ts 3:17-38
```

I have no clue what the problem could be. The module export should be correct.

[Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/806CP.png)

webpack.config.js

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './js/app.ts',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {test: /\.ts$/, use: 'ts-loader'}
        ]
    }
};
```

tsconfig.json

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
        "strictNullChecks": false,
        "lib": [
            "es5", "es2015.core", "dom"
        ],
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "outDir": "dist"
    },
    "include": [
        "js/**/*"
    ]
}
```

src/app.js

```js
import { MyModule } from './MyModule';

let mym = new MyModule();
console.log('Demo');

mym.createTool();
console.log(mym.demoTool(3,4));
```

src/MyModule.ts

```js
export class MyModule {
   createTool() {
    console.log("Test 123");
  }

   demoTool(x:number ,y:number) {
    return x+y;
  }
};
```

src/index.html

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Demo</title>
        <base href="/">
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <script src="dist/bundle.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 190, accepted):

Webpack does not look for `.ts` files by default. You can configure [`resolve.extensions`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-extensions) to look for `.ts`. Don't forget to add the default values as well, otherwise most modules will break because they rely on the fact that the `.js` extension is automatically used.

```
resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.json']
}
```

Comment: And check for typos - in my case I added ts and tsx but had forgotten the dot at the beginning of `.tsx`

Answer (score 60):

Tried all the suggestions above and it still didn't work.

Ended up being the tiniest detail:

In webpack.js, instead of:

```
resolve: {
  extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js']
},
```

The ordering should be:

```
resolve: {
  extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js']
},
```

Don't know why this is necessary, and to be quite honest, I'm beyond caring at this point...

Comment: "Don't know why this is necessary, and to be quite honest, I'm beyond caring at this point..." thank you for that, my sentiments exactly :-).

Comment: Didn't make a difference for me.

Comment: Thank you man, I can't believe it was such an arbitrary thing stopping it from working. 
Can't express the frustration this issue has given me today so thank you for adding this answer.

Answer (score 16):

Leaving this here for posterity, but I had this exact same issue and my problem was that my entry path was not relative but absolute. I changed entry from:

```
entry: 'entry.ts'
```

to

```
entry: './entry.ts'
```

Comment: I am on webpack 4.31.0 and this was the solution! I have  the resolve..extensions... '.ts' part as well, so I could even specify `entry: './entry'`

Comment: In webpack 4.41.5 I solved the error in just the opposite way, went from relative entry to absolute.

Answer (score 6):

I'm a bit late to the party, but is better to use:

```
resolve: {
    extensions: ['.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx', '...']
}
```

`...` means that we'll not overwrite the default, only add to it

Answer (score 1):

I'm using tsconfig instead of webpack which also compiles the submodule to a bundle (index.js).

The issue for me was that I had forgotten to compile the submodule (ie run `tsc` to generate index.js) before referencing it from outside.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the issue is fixed by

```
import Foo from "../Foo.ts";
```

Instead of

```
import Foo from "../Foo";
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue was that I needed to upgrade node and npm.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have tsconfig.json in the same root directory as your webpack.config.js as well.

I had my tsconfig in the root directory so I could share it between my client and server folder, but it needed to be in the client folder where webpack.config.js was.