# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve the typescript file when adding typescript to a CRA app

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, create-react-app

I'm trying to add `typescript` to my project and write new components with typescript. I followed the documentation but I'm got this error:
`can't resolve [the typescript file]`

this happens even with a fresh `create-react-app` project.
according to [CRA documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-typescript/) for adding `typescript` To an existing Create React App project, first, we must install `typescript` and `type definition files`:

```
npm install --save typescript @types/node @types/react @types/react-dom @types/jest
```

almost done!
rename a `js/jsx` file to `tsx` and restart your development server!

for simplicity, I'm creating a `typescript` file named `test.tsx` that contains the `Test` component:

```
export default function Test(){
    return (
        <div>this is test to see typescirpt</div>
    )
}
```

and importing it to the `main.js` and rendering it:

```
import Test from "./test";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Test />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

now I'm restarting the development server (I closed the previous one with `CRTL+c`) with `npm start`.
I got this error:

```
Compiled with problems:

ERROR in ./src/App.js 4:0-26

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './test' in '/home/g/w/ts/test_adding_ts/src'
```

I used a fresh `create-react-app` project, followed the documentation, and saw this error. (why?)
this is my installed dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.0.1",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.4.1",
    "@types/node": "^17.0.24",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.5",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.1",
    "react": "^18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.6.3",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
```

Comment: "Webpack does not look for .ts files by default.": 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43595555/webpack-cant-resolve-typescript-modules

Comment: documentation I mentioned says: just to these two steps (installing requirements and restarting the development server)

Comment: Try: import Test from "./test.tsx"

Comment: this is a wired suggestion that you make, CRA says do these to achieve `typescript` and a tsconfig file. so now how do I create the tsconfig file? with `tsc --init`. are these works safe to do? why not simply follow the documentation??

Comment: Guess, you already did follow the documentation! Then, it's normal to start by narrowing up the problem..! I didn't write an answer but a comment :v

Answer (score 24):

Have you created a config file: tsconfig.json in your root directory? I didn't see this being mentioned in the question.

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

If not created, you can create one in root directory alongside package.json and paste the above configs. OR else already created, you can replace the existing config by above config and recheck.

Comment: [in this part of documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-typescript/#getting-started-with-typescript-and-react) said it will be created automatically.

Comment: also, I downgraded to CRA 4.0.3 and it created automatically. beside this look at [this part of source code](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/f99167c014a728ec856bda14f87181d90b050813/packages/react-scripts/scripts/utils/verifyTypeScriptSetup.js#L41) it checks the existence of .ts files and creates tsconfig file.

Comment: maybe I must create a new fresh CRA app with "typescript" template and copy my files there.

Answer (score 5):

[CRA Documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-typescript/#installation) guide works if follow each step as is but it's **very** tricky when saying "rename any file to be a TypeScript file". According to [source code](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/main/packages/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js#L321) of `create-react-app` to use typescript your app [should contain](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/main/packages/react-scripts/scripts/start.js#L94) `./tsconfig.json` file.

Simple renaming, as described in guide, works only for `./src/index.(js|ts|jsx|tsx)` file but all imports will fail as far as `create-react-app` [configurates](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/main/packages/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js#L321) `webpack` to exclude all typescript files.

Minimal `./tsconfig.json` file, as I personally checked for CRA version 5.0.1 is a following one:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "jsx": "react"
  }
}
```

Comment: Suggest changing `"jsx": "react"` to `"jsx": "react-jsx"`

Comment: Not sure "react-jsx" property value is compatible with create-react-app but, what is more important, "react" produces more __classic__ output (React.createElement)

Answer (score 2):

I also searched a lot and finally I found the useful way for myself:

I added tsconfig.json file in the root and added these codes to it :

[tsConfig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VK33a.png)

I got help form [this site](https://blog.logrocket.com/common-typescript-module-problems-and-how-to-solve/) to solve it

the entire code of my tsconfig.json was this:

```js
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "*": [
                "*",
                "components/*"
            ]
        },
        "allowJs": false,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "allowUnreachableCode": false,
        "allowUnusedLabels": false,
        "alwaysStrict": true,
        "charset": "utf8",
        "checkJs": false,
        "declaration": true,
        "disableSizeLimit": false,
        "downlevelIteration": false,
        "emitBOM": false,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "importHelpers": false,
        "inlineSourceMap": false,
        "inlineSources": false,
        "isolatedModules": false,
        "lib": [
            "es2017",
            "esnext.asynciterable"
        ],
        "locale": "en-us",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "newLine": "lf",
        "noEmit": false,
        "noEmitHelpers": false,
        "noEmitOnError": true,
        "noErrorTruncation": true,
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noImplicitThis": true,
        "noStrictGenericChecks": false,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "noUnusedParameters": true,
        "noImplicitUseStrict": false,
        "noLib": false,
        "noResolve": false,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "strict": true,
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "suppressExcessPropertyErrors": false,
        "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": false,
        "target": "es2017",
        "traceResolution": false,
        "rootDir": "",
        "outDir": "../../build/lib",
        "typeRoots": []
    },
    "include": [
        "**/*.ts"
    ],
    "exclude": []
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just had this issue myself. For me, webpack was not resolving typescript files.

If you're using webpack - add the following to your webpack.config.js

```
resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.jsx', '.json'],
},
```

Answer (score 0):

After 3 days of insanity, what worked for me was updating the `tsconfig.json` file by adding the `rootDir` and `outDir` property like this:

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    //...
    "outDir": "../../dist",
    "rootDir": "."
  },
```

Then delete all `dist` inside the project. After that I ran `npm run build` and it worked. Hope it helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Despite what the docs suggest it seems when migrating from JS to TS you do actually need to provide a `tsconfig.json` file.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext", "webworker"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As **bnays mhz** said you have to create a `tsconfig.json` in root and add that same content he provided, also you have to rename all `.js` files to `.tsx` and it will compile your application with Type errors which you have to resolve manually.

But instead of doing this, I suggest you use the `typescript` template.

```
npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript
```

It will configure everything for you, and you can start with ease.

Answer (score -1):

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext", "webworker"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).